# Building DD4T 2.0 Templates project

Tags: 2013-sp1, dd4t, templating

I'm trying to Build the project downloaded from:

https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates

But, When I try it I get the errors:

```
Error   18  Unable to find version '1.0.3' of package 'sdl-tridion-templating-2011-sp1'.    DD4T.Templates
Error   19  Unable to find version '1.0.1' of package 'sdl-tridion-templating-2013-sp1'.    DD4T.Templates
```

It seems a problem with dependencies.

I try to find it in nugget but I can't.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: at a guess, these are the tridion libraries, which they are not allowed to distribute. you may have to get them from a Tridion server (well, 2 in this case)

Comment: I think DD4T has a private nuget feed as part of the build. You could create those packages and add them to a local filesystem based nuget feed

Comment: Do you have all of the DLLs relevant to your project added to your library? https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/downloads/detail?name=DLLs-1.31.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nuno mentioned Tridion libraries are not allowed to be distributed.

In the root of the DD4T.Tridion Templates repository there is a "[dependencies](https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates/tree/master/dependencies)" directory within that for each Tridion version a sub directory. Copy The Tridion libraries into the correct directory and rebuild the solution. find here the list of Tridion [dependencies](https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Core/wiki/SDL-Tridion-Dependencies)